# Pivot Viewer, rounding of decimal values

Tags: pivotviewer, cxml-collectionxml

I have a pivot collection that has a numeric facet, however when the value is being displayed it keeps rounding to the nearest whole number.

Is there a way in which I can show the full number with the decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking in CXML?  If so, there is a Format attribute you can set on the facet category.  It only works for `DateTime` and `Numeric`, but that will work in your case.  The accepted format strings are .NET format strings.

Check here for full documentation of the [PivotViewer CXML Schema](http://web.archive.org/web/20120529021514/http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/collection-xml-schema)

Comment: The format string you should use is just "c", not "{0:C}" in this case.  You omit the placeholder because there is only one, and it's not necessary.  It's equivalent to calling `1.ToString("c");`